# Using HTTP in Angular 2: @angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js/src not found

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to use HTTP module in angular 2. Here are the parts of code I added, hoping it'd be enough (not including usage of it):

**systemjs.config.js** (mapping)

'`@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js'`

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Http }  from '@angular/http';

(...)

@NgModule({imports: [(...), Http]
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": { (...), "@angular/http": "2.0.0"}
```

Errors I get:

```
zone.js:1274 GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js/src 404 (Not Found)scheduleTask @ zone.js:1274ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:216Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:153(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1304send @ VM700:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1051(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1781ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:478(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1780(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2809(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3387(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3701(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4093(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4556(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4825(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:407ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:203Zone.run @ zone.js:96(anonymous function) @ zone.js:462ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:236Zone.runTask @ zone.js:136drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:368ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:308

(index):31 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js/src(…)
```

I checked and file http.umd.js is available at *@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js*. Why is angular checking @angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js/**src**?

Comment: somewhere in your code you imported something from @angular2/http/src

Comment: thanks @Supamiu, that was it!

Answer (score 0):

You are using **`Http`** wrong way in Angular2, It should be,

```
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule,HttpModule],
    ...
})
```

Now in **component** `eg. AppComponent`

```
import { Http }  from '@angular/http';
```